# Do Java parameterized messages interfere with method signatures?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm updating Log4j from v1 to v2.  The code I'm updating has many instances of the Log4j `Logger.debug(Object message, Throwable throwable)` method and signature where `message` is constructed by string concatenation.  For example:

```
/* Log4j v1 */
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();

String datafilter = "blah";
try {
    /* code */
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug("Compiler Exception for " + datafilter, e);
    System.exit(3);
}
```

When updating to Log4j v2, the [Log4j migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) states that parameterized messages like `logger.info("hi {}", userName)` should be used instead of string concatenation.  Thus, the updated code would look something like this:

```
/* Log4j v2 */
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

String datafilter = "blah";
try {
    /* code */
}
catch (Exception e) {
    /* Is the following correct? */
    logger.debug("Compiler Exception for {}", datafilter, e);
    System.exit(3);
}
```

However, the method signature for `logger.debug("Compiler Exception for {}", datafilter, e)` looks off to me because the arguments for the parameterized message are mixed in with the other arguments to `Logger.debug()` (or `Logger.info()` or whatever).

Is this the correct way to introduce parameterized messages into Log4j?  Will the compiler automatically understand which arguments are for subsitution and which are expected parts of the method signature, or do I need to delineate the parameterized message in some way?

Answer (score 1):

*"Will the compiler automatically understand which arguments are for subsitution and which are expected parts of the method signature"*

No, the compiler does not understand the special meaning of the `Throwable` argument in the second case, but Log4j2 does:

- in the first case the compiler chooses the [`debug(CharSequence, Throwable)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#debug-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Throwable-) and Log4j2 is sure that you wanted to attach an exception to your message,
- in the second case the compiler chooses the [`debug(String, Object, Object)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#debug-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) method, Log4j2 counts the number of `{}` placeholders in your string (which is one) and if the first unused parameter is a `Throwable`, it uses it as the exception attached to the logging event.

Try:

```java
logger.debug("Compiler Exception for {}", datafilter, e);
logger.debug("Compiler Exception for {}: {}", datafilter, e);
```

to better understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't fully understand it, but it sounds like you expect the `logger.debug()` line in the 2nd example, the one for Log4j v2, to work as written?

Comment: Yes, the first line will print the exception's stack trace (i.e. it will treat `e` as an exception), while the second line will just print `e.toString()` (i.e. it will treat `e` as a simple parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the documentation of [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html), there is no method signature that allows you, while formatting your message, to pass the rised exception at the same time.

You can use the `String.format()` Java method for the message parameter and use this [signature](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html) instead:

```
logger.debug(String.format("Compiler Exception for %s", datafilter), e);
```